# When will Push Kit include the android:exported attributes required for Android 12?

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-push-notification

The latest version of Push Kit (5.3.0.304) displays an error when compiling targetting Android 12:

> Installation failed due to: 'INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED:
> Failed parse during installPackageLI:
> /data/app/vmdl520427088.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #349):
> com.huawei.hms.support.api.push.PushMsgReceiver: Targeting S+ (version
> 10000 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported
> be defined when intent filters are present'

This error appears due to Android 12 requering all intent-filters to include the android:exported attribute. This is exposed on the Android 12 changes page: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported

What is the approximate release date for the version of Push Kit that includes this changes?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we cannot predict the future.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update**:

Just confirmed with the team, pls upgrade the push kit version to **6.1.0.300** will solve your problem.

```
    // push kit
    implementation 'com.huawei.hms:push:6.1.0.300'
```

---

Thanks for your feedback, As confirmed by the team, we will release a version for Android 12 as soon as possible,and will let you know when it's released.

Comment: After much researching, solved for me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please post more details of the Androidmanifest.xml file. Following functional configuration is provided for your reference. It works with or without the “exported” attribute on Huawei HMS devices.

Manifest file
[image]