# Crash Executing Android APP targeting API 31 with Huawei HMS Base 6.1.0.302 on Android 12

Tags: java, android, kotlin, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-push-notification

I have updated my application for target API 31 and now i am having crashes in runtime when executing only in phones with Android 12. The crash is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: HuaweiApiManager
    Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 4873
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.example.myapp: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
    Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
        at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivityAsUser(PendingIntent.java:458)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:444)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:408)
        at com.huawei.hms.api.b.getErrPendingIntent(HuaweiApiAvailabilityImpl.java:10)
        at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.BaseHmsClient.resolution(BaseHmsClient.java:3)
        at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.BaseHmsClient.checkAvailabilityAndConnect(BaseHmsClient.java:34)
        at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.BaseHmsClient.connect(BaseHmsClient.java:1)
        at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.HuaweiApiManager$ConnectionManager.connect(HuaweiApiManager.java:21)
        at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.HuaweiApiManager$ConnectionManager.sendRequest(HuaweiApiManager.java:24)
        at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.HuaweiApiManager.connectAndSendRequest(HuaweiApiManager.java:8)
        at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.HuaweiApiManager.handleMessage(HuaweiApiManager.java:7)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

This error is related with [When will Push Kit include the android:exported attributes required for Android 12?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68373122/when-will-push-kit-include-the-androidexported-attributes-required-for-android/68373813#68373813)

What is the approximate release date for the version of HMS Base that fix this error?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. The team confirms that the development is underway and the new version will be released in the next few days, and i will let you know when it's released.

Answer (score 2):

A new version of the base SDK has been released ：

`implementation 'com.huawei.hms:base:6.2.0.300'`

This issue has been fixed, you can explicitly depend on this version of base sdk first, which should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks! Needed to add this package to my build.gradle, now app starts without any problems.